# How to remove a pop-up div appended with .append() method using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup

I am trying to figure out how can I remove a pop-up div element using the `.remove()` jQuery method. I have a div which is appended to the #main div when the I click on an element with class ".popUpTrigger". Then I would like to remove this appended HTML code when I click on the pop-up itself.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
       <button class="popUpTrigger">Click to trigger the popUp!</button>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

My jscript.js:

```
    function popUpCreate(idToAppend, popUpCode) {
       $(function() {
            $(idToAppend).append(popUpCode);
       });
     }


    $(function() {
        $(".popUpTrigger").click(function() {
        popUpCreate("#main", "<div class='popUpBg'><div class='popUpItSelf'>Hello!</div></div>");
         });
     });

  $(function() {
    $(".popUpBg").click(function() {
         $(".popUpBg").remove();
       });
   });
```

The style.css file:

```
      .popUpBg {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999999;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    cursor:pointer;
      }

      .popUpItSelf {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9999999;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-401px;
    margin-top:-301px;
    background:white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 4em;
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:200px;
         }
```

But it does not work, I want the pop-up to be removed when I click on the `.popUpBg` (which is the pop-up background).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: you need to delegate click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You append an handler on click for an object (the background) that not yet exists.

First, I rewrite your own code to be more readable

```
function popUpCreate(idToAppend, popUpCode) {
   $(idToAppend).append(popUp);
}

$(".popUpTrigger").click(function() {
    popUpCreate("#main", "<div class='popUpBg'><div class='popUpItSelf'>Hello!</div></div>");
});


$(".popUpBg").click(function() {
    $(".popUpBg").remove();
});
```

Now, I make the correction

```
function popUpCreate(idToAppend, popUpCode) {
    $(idToAppend).append(popUp);
    $(".popUpBg").click(function() {
        $(".popUpBg").remove();
    });
}

$(".popUpTrigger").click(function() {
    popUpCreate("#main", "<div class='popUpBg'><div class='popUpItSelf'>Hello!</div></div>");
});
```

Comment: So with your solution the handler is automatically built every time the function popUpCreate() is called am I right?

Comment: Thanks! There's only one thing. Even when I click on the popUpItSelf the pop-up is removed, how can I avoid that?

Comment: use the event params in event handler with, something like ... click(function(event) { if(event.target ... ) ...} );  or maybe currentTarget I don't remember

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand, I new with JQuery... Could you please explain me more specifically, please?

Comment: Ok, on the click event handler, you can have the event argument that gives you all the informations on the real click event. So, check that $(event.target).hasClass('popUpBg') and now, you can be sure that it's the background that is clicked, not a child of the background...

Comment: I changed the function like this:
`function popUpForm(idToApp, popUpCode) {
  $(idToApp).append(popUpCode);
  $(".popUpBg").click(function() {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('popUpBg')) {
     $(".popUpBg").remove();
    }
    });
}`

It works fine in Chrome and Opera, but not in Firefox, do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

This is to remove the popup by clicking on the background

```
$('.popUpBg').on('click', function() {
    $('.popUpItSelf').remove();
});
```

To remove both the background and the pop up, just do this.

```
$('.popUpBg').on('click', function() {
    $('.popUpItSelf, .popUpBg').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, The above answer suited for me.